# mvc 5 - getting value into id from loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So here is my cshtml file -

```
@model Portal.ViewModel.DocumentViewModel
@using Portal.Helpers

@foreach (var item in Model.Documents)
{
    <div id="{@item.id}linkdiv">
        text
    </div>
}
```

this loops over maybe 5-8 records and I need to uniquely identify each `div` that I add.

This sample results in id's of "{2}linkdiv"

What is the syntax to get id = "2linkdiv"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
@model Portal.ViewModel.DocumentViewModel
@using Portal.Helpers

@foreach (var item in Model.Documents)
{
    <div id="@(item.id)linkdiv">
        text
    </div>
}
```

The parents encapsulate the razor statement.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Stephen's answer, you could reverse your naming convention:

```
@model Portal.ViewModel.DocumentViewModel
@using Portal.Helpers

@foreach (var item in Model.Documents)
{
    <div id="linkdiv@item.id">
        text
    </div>
}
```